# Get Json rest API parsing in Python

Tags: python, json, api

Need small help on getting the data through API in json response.
I am getting the data for another apis but this one looks little bit different so asking.

** this is provided by the provider:-**

```
e.g. POST https://yyyy/analytics/generi
{
    "report_definition_id": "yyyyyyyyyy",
    "parameters": {
        "from": "2021-01-26",
        "to": "2021-02-05"  Can you please edit this to include yesterday date always?
    }
}
Usual header:
Authorization:Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Content-Type:application/json
```

**I am using this for another API so can you amend this**

```
def fp_data_processing():
    authurl="https://xxxxxxx/connect/token"
    payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read admin"
    headers={
             'Authorization': "Basic xxxxxxxx",
             'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
    response = requests.request("POST", authurl, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response_json  = response.json()

    #Only one when successful API response :200
    if(response.status_code==200):
        logging.info('API Authorization Completed:Moving to Extract:')
        purchaseurl = "https://yyyyy/analytics/generic"
        start=time.time()
        querystring=  {"report_definition_id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz","parameters": {"from": "2021-01-26","to": "2021-02-05"}}
        headers =     {'Authorization':"Bearer "+response_json['access_token']}
        response = requests.request("GET", purchaseurl, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

**but getting this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcustomer_kpi.py", line 60, in <module>
    fp_data_processing()
  File "tcustomer_kpi.py", line 36, in fp_data_processing
    if response.json():
  File "/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: By looking at "JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None" before decoding check if the var is not None

Comment: @juan how to check it?

Comment: @juan can you tell me the code and the structure I have used is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the response that you get is json

```py
response = requests.request("POST", authurl, data=payload, headers=headers)

try:
   response_json = response.json()
except ValueError:
   # Do something if you dont get a json
```

Comment: the response from post response is json but after that the below response is showing the decoding error

    if(response.status_code==200):
        logging.info('API Authorization Completed:Moving to Extract:')
        purchaseurl = "https://yyyyy/analytics/generic"
        start=time.time()
        querystring=  {"report_definition_id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz","parameters": {"from": "2021-01-26","to": "2021-02-05"}}
        headers =     {'Authorization':"Bearer "+response_json['access_token']}
        response = requests.request("GET", purchaseurl, headers=headers, params=querystring)

Comment: @json also I am using 
headers={
             'Authorization': "Basic xxxxxxxx",
             'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }

but provided said to use content type :application/json but when I am using that it shows invalid request